# Callback function returns object instead of number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have the following code for getting the length of an array using an Ajax call. A callback is used here. However, I keep getting `[object Object]` instead of the actual count. What am I doing wrong?

```
var count = countArray().done(handle_countArray);   

alert(count); // shows [object Object]



function handle_countArray(array) {
    var count = array.length;
    alert(count); // gets correct length

    return count; // should return correct length
}

function countArray() {
    return $.ajax({ url: "..." });
}
```

Comment: - asynchronicity

Comment: Can you `console.log(array)` and paste the output here?

Comment: @Igor isn't that what the `done()` callback is for?

Comment: @Igor I thought callbacks are supposed to fix that?

Comment: @AP., jebmarcus_returns - no, `done` still returns the same `xhr` object as `$.ajax`. That's why you can chain-call `done`, `fail`, `always` etc.

Comment: @AP. console.log(array) inside the `handle_countArray` function returns `[Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Comment: @Igor I didn't notice the assignment to `count`

Comment: @igor this doesn't make sense because done() is designed to fix asynchronous issues? no?

Comment: @jebmarcus_returns haha, no. it just allows you to apply a callback. Within said callback, you can access the results. You cannot however return those results back to the outside because the outside has already finished.

Comment: @jebmarcus_returns You cannot assign count synchronously in this case. Use count inside your `handle_countArray` callback

Comment: @jebmarcus_returns - depends on what your understanding of "fix" is.